# Does anyone know what is beta in Cox-nnet paper?

Tags: neural-networks, survival, cox-model

I was going through the methods in this paper: [Cox-nnet: An artificial neural network method for prognosis prediction of high-throughput omics data <sup>[1]</sup>](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5909924/)

There they define (Equation 4)

$$\theta_i=\boldsymbol{G \circ (Wx_i+b)^T\boldsymbol\beta}$$

$\boldsymbol{W}_{H \times J}$ are the layer coefficients, $\boldsymbol b$ are the biases and $\boldsymbol G$ is the activation function.

What does $\boldsymbol\beta$ mean in the context of Equation 4?

---

<sub><sup>[[1]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5909924/)</sup> Ching T, Zhu X, Garmire LX. Cox-nnet: An artificial neural network method for prognosis prediction of high-throughput omics data. PLoS Comput Biol. 2018;14(4):e1006076. Published 2018 Apr 10. doi:10.1371/journal.pcbi.1006076</sub>

Comment: Seeing the question has an answer, I don't see reason for closing it.

Answer (score 3):

Look back at Equation (2) in the linked paper:

$$ \theta_i = \boldsymbol{x_i^t \beta}$$

"where $\theta_i$ is the log hazard ratio for patient $i$."

Regression coefficients are typically represented by the symbol $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. In a standard Cox model as in the above equation, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ would represent the vector of coefficients that translate the covariate values $\boldsymbol{x_i}$ for patient $i$ into the estimated log hazard ratio for that patient, via the indicated dot product $\boldsymbol{x_i^t \beta}$.

For the neural net developed in that paper, the $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ in the equations that you show would then represent the regression coefficients for the covariate values $\boldsymbol{x_i}$ as transformed by the weight matrix, the node bias coefficients, and the specified activation function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind reply.  If I understood that correctly, you mean, that if we were to distill the neural net into a non-linear regression model, ..each covariate would have a coefficient $\beta$ (that would be a function of other variables and not constant).. and that is what they show here?

Comment: @AasthaDua not quite. The nonlinearities are all encompassed in the activation function applied to the weighted and biased covariate values in $\boldsymbol{x}$. The $\beta$ coefficient values would be constants, although determining their values would involve using information from all of the variables. Technically this would still be considered a linear regression model as it is linear in terms of the coefficients. A nonlinear transformation of a predictor variable (as, say, with the frequently used log transform) does not by itself make a model “nonlinear” as that term is used in statistics.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! That makes it super clear. Can I think of this equation as a 2 layer neural net? First has params W and b. This is followed by a layer of non-linearity G. And that is followed by $\beta$ - the weights of the last layer of this neural net - which give out the output of the net.

Comment: @AasthaDua that would be my understanding: the hidden layer applies the activation function to each predictor after weighting and biasing, the output from each predictor is multiplied by the corresponding $\beta$ value, and those contributions from the predictors are added to provide the combined linear predictor as an output. Note, however, that I have no substantive experience with neural nets and their hidden layers, just with Cox models.